# Parse multi attribute values in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am developing an application and
 i want to parse the xml but when 
it comes in the way of multiple attribute 
then how will u do it using the  nsxmlparser

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding='utf-8' ?>
<Responses Id='7465'>
<Response RequestID="101" FunctionStatus="0" Message="OK"/>

<Result>

<PrimaryID>
<Item ID="1" Text="Aadhar Card"/>
<Item ID="2" Text="Voters ID"/>
<Item ID="3" Text="Driving Licence"/>
<Item ID="4" Text="PAN Card"/>
<Item ID="5" Text="Passport"/>
</PrimaryID>

<Sex>
<Item ID="1" Text="Male"/>
<Item ID="2" Text="Female"/>
</Sex>

<Title>
<Item ID="1" Text="Mr"/>
<Item ID="2" Text="Ms"/>
<Item ID="3" Text="Mrs"/>
</Title>
</Result>

</Responses>
```

Comment: Have you tried something or just wondering how to do it?

Comment: yes i have tried  but if it is single tag then then ok

Comment: Well then `attributeDict` in `parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:` delegate method is what you're looking for I guess ([see docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008632-CH1-SW5))...

Answer (score 0):

With XMLReader you can get it in a dictionary like this :

**file.xml in your resource bundle :**

```
- (void)dataFromXML
{
    // Error
    NSError *error = nil;

    // Request
    NSMutableDictionary *xmlDic = nil;
    NSData *xmlData = nil;

    // Get XML
    xmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"xml"]];

    // Parse the XML Data into a NSDictionary
    xmlDic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:xmlData error:&error]];

    // Configure Dictionary
    xmlDic = [[[xmlDic objectForKey:@"Responses"] objectForKey:@"Response"] objectForKey:@"Result"];
    NSLog(@"%@", xmlDic);
}
```

**file.xml on the web :**

```
- (void)dataWSFromXML
{
    // Error
    NSError *error = nil;

    // Request
    NSURLRequest *request = nil;
    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSMutableDictionary *xmlDic = nil;
    NSData *xmlData = nil;

    // Get XML
    request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourXMLfile.xml"]];
    xmlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error]; // You can improve this request

    // Parse the XML Data into a NSDictionary
    xmlDic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:xmlData error:&error]];

    // Configure Dictionary
    xmlDic = [[[xmlDic objectForKey:@"Responses"] objectForKey:@"Response"] objectForKey:@"Result"];
    NSLog(@"%@", xmlDic);
}
```

But I change your XML like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Responses Id='7465'>
    <Response RequestID="101" FunctionStatus="0" Message="OK">
        <Result>

            <PrimaryID>
                <Item ID="1" Text="Aadhar Card"/>
                <Item ID="2" Text="Voters ID"/>
                <Item ID="3" Text="Driving Licence"/>
                <Item ID="4" Text="PAN Card"/>
                <Item ID="5" Text="Passport"/>
            </PrimaryID>

            <Sex>
                <Item ID="1" Text="Male"/>
                <Item ID="2" Text="Female"/>
            </Sex>

            <Title>
                <Item ID="1" Text="Mr"/>
                <Item ID="2" Text="Ms"/>
                <Item ID="3" Text="Mrs"/>
            </Title>
        </Result>
    </Response>
</Responses>
```